# Using relative instead of fixed size in CSS

Tags: css, font-size

I want to use relative size instead of fixed size. I want to use em.

My CSS is:

```
body{
     font:10px;
}

#wrap {
   font:1.2em;
}

#wrap ul li {
   padding-left:2em;
}
```

What is value of the `li`'s padding in px? I would have guessed it's 2.0*10 = 20px, but it looks like it's taking 1em = 12px, I mean it taking it parent size.

I would like for it to take 1x the parent font-size in px (that means font-size of `body` not `wrap`).

Comment: If you want to use `em` measurements, why aren't you using them everywhere? ie. Why are you setting your `body` font size to 10px (which is far too small on my screen for instance).

Comment: @Matthew it's almost universal that if you plan on using relative font sizes, your baseline should be 10px because it makes the math for calculating everything else much simpler. Even if all the text ends up being 1.2 or larger.

Comment: What evidence do you have that using 10px is "almost universal"? That seems like a very odd thing to do.

Comment: There is nothing even remotely universal about that. It's one method, but not a very good one in my mind. Why would you use a base font size that has no particular relation to either your intended font size or a reasonable line-height? I always use relative font sizes, and it requires a lot of extra math to keep the baseline under control, but it's well worth it for the flexibility of the result. I recommend this article for getting started: http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm

There is no way around the extra math as you want in your example. You need 1.666em to get 20px.

Answer (score 1):

ems are always relative to their parent element, as you stated. Additionally, an element's non-font dimensions are always calculated relative to its font dimensions - i.e. if you say `font-size:1.2em;padding:2em` - that element's padding will be 2x the font size which is 1.2x the size of its next defined parent element.

The solution is to use more math. If your wrapper element is 1.2em, and you want an inner element padding to be double the baseline size, you should use `t=i*x`, where `t` is target size, `i` is inherited size, and `x` is the desired size. So for our case, 2em is the target size; 1.2em is the inherited size:

`2em = 1.2em * x` => `x = 1.67`

So padding should be **1.67em**.

Answer (score 0):

the font size of `#wrap ul li` is 10px*1.2em*2em, thus padding-left:24px;

it always takes the font size of the parent element (in your case `#wrap`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is em calculated parent font size or parent that has font size in px. Because some where i read 1em = 1/parent font-size in PX.

Comment: 1em is the width of the letter “M”

Comment: That's correct, but width of that 'M' depends up on font size. Then  1em = 1/parent font-size in PX

Comment: why 1/font-size oO? 1em = width of letter M in font-size of parent element

Comment: ya that's only my question. Is 1em is width of letter M in font-size of parent element OR is it width of letter M in font-size of parent element/grandparent (in case font-size is not defined in PX) which has font-size in PX.

Comment: em is derived from the first element with a set size (by default, body gets a size set from the browser). then it calculates all font sizes from body down to your element. if you don’t specify a font-size it is the same (=1em) as the parent element