# is font/text sizing in % more accessible and manageble than em?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, font-size

Both article are proving this.

http://www.kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/relative/

I want to know SO users view?

Comment: The second link isn't really related to %-vs.-em

Comment: @Anon - yes it's not about % vs em but it's using % as a exapmle which is easy to use and manage. that was my point

Comment: You could write the entire article using `em` for the examples and it wouldn't change anything. The article has nothing to do with your argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only differences between % and 100 * em (for setting font size) is that there are a few browser bugs relating to the use of em units (which can be worked around with an explicit `body { font-size: 100%; }` and then using em units thereafter.)

The kyleschaeffer article is, frankly, rubbish. It leaves out half the facts.

The maxdesign is decent, but shows its age. It was written in '03, and the bugs it talks about are in Opera 6 and Netscape 4 — both of which are obsolete.

Comment: have u seen the conclousion at the end of first linked articles and second link has all the solution for problems but it's in % which is easy to use

Comment: Yes, I've seen the conclusion. My comments stand.

Comment: bugs of Max-design article is still a bug with relative values see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377449/problem-with-em-unit

Comment: There is no bug in that question, just an inadvisable combination of nested relative units with an absolute root unit (making the whole advantage of relative font units moot), and an unusual use of em for non-font-related measurements.

Comment: Even that combination isn't causing the problem which led the question. That was because the author was trying to use relative units as if they were absolute units… which they aren't.